# DX11 vertices not drawn over a certain number

Tags: c++, graphics, directx-11

I'm trying to render a fullscreen tessellated mesh. It works as expected for up to around 250x250 vertices, but past that, it cuts off after the top half or so (depending on how tessellated I set the mesh).

I have a vertex and index vector, which I populate programmatically as a trianglelist. I suspect it might be related to the buffer size of the vertex buffer, since the number of vertices/indices seems right, but when I try to increase the bytewidth allocation, I get a memory access violation.

The vertex data struct defined as such:

```
struct SimpleVertex
{
    XMFLOAT3 Pos;
    XMFLOAT2 Tex;
};
```

To initialize the buffers, I use:

```
D3D11_BUFFER_DESC bd;
bd.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
bd.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
bd.CPUAccessFlags = 0;

...

D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA InitData;
InitData.pSysMem = &(meshVertices[0]);

...

D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC meshLayout[] =
{
    { "POSITION", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0, 0, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
    { "TEXCOORD", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32_FLOAT, 0, 12, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
};
```

Vertex buffer:

```
...
bd.ByteWidth = sizeof(SimpleVertex) * (UINT)(meshVertices.size());
...
hr = g_pd3dDevice->CreateBuffer(&bd, &InitData, &g_pMeshVertexBuffer);
```

Index buffer:

```
...
bd.ByteWidth = sizeof(WORD) * (UINT)(meshIndices.size());
...
hr = g_pd3dDevice->CreateBuffer(&bd, &InitData, &g_pMeshIndexBuffer);
```

Draw call:

```
void RenderMesh(){
    g_pImmediateContext->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &g_pRenderTargetView, g_pDepthStencilView);

    UINT stride = sizeof(SimpleVertex);
    UINT offset = 0;

    g_pImmediateContext->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &g_pMeshVertexBuffer, &stride, &offset);
    g_pImmediateContext->IASetInputLayout(g_pMeshVertexLayout);
    g_pImmediateContext->IASetIndexBuffer(g_pMeshIndexBuffer, DXGI_FORMAT_R16_UINT, 0);

    g_pImmediateContext->VSSetShader(g_pMeshVertexShader, nullptr, 0);
    g_pImmediateContext->PSSetShader(g_pMeshPixelShader, nullptr, 0);
    g_pImmediateContext->PSSetSamplers(0, 1, &g_pSamplerLinear);

    g_pImmediateContext->DrawIndexed(numMeshIndices, 0, 0);
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: are 16-bit indices still supported? If I remember correctly D3D 11 doesn't support 16-bit indices, not sure though. Have you tried setting the data type of indices to 32-bit?

Comment: @Asesh 16-bit indexes are supported as long as `DXGI_FORMAT_R16_UINT` format flag is used. As for question it does not list most of the relevant code, you should add actual buffer creation and drawing code here.

Comment: @VTT sorry, I'm new to DX11 so I wasn't completely sure what to include. I've edited them in. The code I wrote builds upon http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff729724.aspx.

Comment: 250x250 vertices is about 65536, that is 16-bit index range, so I guess you should switch to 32 bit index.

Comment: @VTT that was the issue, thanks so much!

Comment: What Direct3D hardware feature level are you using? Keep in mind Feature Level 9.1 does not support 32bit indices. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476876.aspx)